# Having problems with mapping forEach and Reduce onto a Map Object

Tags: javascript, loops, foreach

This same approach works with objects when used with object values. But how do I make it work on map objects?

```js
const one = new Map ();
one.set ('part1', {section1: 1, section2: 'one'});
one.set ('part2', {section1: 8, section2: 'eight'});
one.set ('part3', {section1: 5, section2: 'five'});

one.forEach(x => console.log(x.section1));

let temp1 = one.forEach(x => x.section1);
console.log(temp1);

let temp2 = one.forEach(x => x.section1).reduce((sum, cur) => sum + cur);
console.log(temp2);
```

Comment: it actually gives an error `"TypeError: can't access property \"reduce\", one.forEach(...) is undefined",`

Comment: @JaromandaX Yet, forEach successfully gives 1,8,5

Comment: sure, but `forEach` doesn't return anything

Comment: You should read the doc of `Map.prototype.forEach`

Comment: `let temp = [...one.values()].map(x => x.section1).reduce((sum, cur) => sum + cur);`

Comment: @Ele - except it would be `Map.prototype.forEach` in this case

Comment: @JaromandaX you're right

Comment: @Ele - it happens now and then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `forEach` returns undefined, so you can't call the function reduce.

Additionally, you don't need to call the function `Array.prototype.map`, with a reduce is just fine.

```js
const one = new Map ();
one.set ('part1', {section1: 1, section2: 'one'});
one.set ('part2', {section1: 8, section2: 'eight'});
one.set ('part3', {section1: 5, section2: 'five'});

let temp2 = Array.from(one.values()).reduce((sum, {section1: cur}) => sum + cur, 0);
console.log(temp2);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answere. Whats the purpose of Array from here and why is it used instead of spread operator `[...one.values()]` like in the other answere?

Comment: @amars the function `Map.prototype.values` returns an `Iterator` which is not an array, so we have to convert it into an Array to be able to use the Array's functions. Therefore, either the spread operator or the function `Array.from` is needed to convert it.

Answer (score 1):

forEach returns `undefined`, you need to use `Array.map` to get values of `section1` in an array to call `reduce` on it.

But the problem is with `Map` you don't have `.map` property. Luckily we `values`.

> The values() method returns a new Iterator object that contains the values for each element in the Map object in insertion order.

So I use `...` over iterator in `[]` to get an array where I can run `.map`

```js
const one = new Map ();
one.set ('part1', {section1: 1, section2: 'one'});
one.set ('part2', {section1: 8, section2: 'eight'});
one.set ('part3', {section1: 5, section2: 'five'});

let temp = [...one.values()].map(x => x.section1).reduce((sum, cur) => sum + cur);
console.log(temp);
```

Alternatively, you don't even need `map` function When you have converted your `Map` values to an array, you can directly call `reduce`

```js
const one = new Map ();
one.set ('part1', {section1: 1, section2: 'one'});
one.set ('part2', {section1: 8, section2: 'eight'});
one.set ('part3', {section1: 5, section2: 'five'});

let tempAlt = [...one.values()].reduce((sum, {section1: cur}) => sum + cur, 0);
console.log(tempAlt);
```

Comment: you may want to explain why you're using values() and ... to make it a reasonable answer